# Confidence interval for Poisson parameter

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

To calculate an upper confidence limit on a Poisson parameter, a $\chi^2$ distribution with probability $P$ and $${\rm degrees \ of \ freedom} = 2X + 2$$ can be used (Nelson, 1982. Applied Life Data Analysis).  I have a sample of 10 observations. My question concerns the variable $X$: is that the total of the sample or the mean?

Comment: I TeXed your equations (verbatim) but what is $P$? The $\chi^2$ distribution only has one parameter.

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Perhaps you could take some of your comments to the answer provided and have another go at expanding (editing) the question so your problem is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

$X$ is the total number of events observed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval .

Comment: it says the total number of events in a given interval.  With 5 observations, I have 5 intervals though.  (Of course I have the same interval for each observation so I don't violate one of the basic assumptions of the Poisson distribution.)

Comment: I need to clarify my terminology. I have randomly sampled from a Poisson distribution 10 times lets say.  I have 10 observations; each with one random value (say Y) from the Poisson I sampled from.  So my question: is X the total of Y (Y1-Y10) or the mean of Y1-Y10?

Comment: @user11920 - if you read a little further down in the section of the wikipedia article, it says "... $k = \sum_{i=1}^Nk_i$, which makes $X$, or $k$ as the notation may be, the total number of events observed.

Comment: and this ?: calculate an interval for μ=nλ, and then derive the interval for λ.

Comment: If you have an interval for $n\lambda$, the interval for $\lambda$ just equals the one for $n\lambda$ divided by $n$, and vice versa.